# Stanford NLP: print parser tree in tree format

Tags: tree, stanford-nlp

this is a silly question, but how can i print the result of the NLP parse tree in tree format?

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Annotation document =
                new Annotation("My dog also likes eating sausage.");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,parse");
            StanfordCoreNLP pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
            pipeline.annotate(document);
            for (CoreMap sentence : document.get(CoreAnnotations.SentencesAnnotation.class)) {
              Tree constituencyParse = sentence.get(TreeCoreAnnotations.TreeAnnotation.class);
              System.out.println(constituencyParse);

        }
    }
```

Upon Execution, i get following result in the Eclipse console:

```
(ROOT (S (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog)) (ADVP (RB also)) (VP (VBZ likes) (NP (JJ eating) (NN sausage))) (. .)))
```

Is there any way to print this in the actual tree format i.e., something like this?

```
(ROOT
 (S
   (NP (PRP$ My) (NN dog))
   (ADVP (RB also))
   (VP (VBZ likes)
     (S
       (VP (VBG eating)
        (NP (NN sausage)))))
(. .)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following statement will print the tree in print format.

```
tree.pennPrint();
```